# How can I prove the following equality?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need to prove:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {k\choose 2}\cdot{{n-k}\choose 2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {k\choose 3}\cdot(n-k).$$

I wasn't able to have any progress with algebra, I tried to think about a combinatorical proof:

Let's imagine there are $n$ people in a row and we need to choose $4.$ 
One way will be to take the $k$ "leftest" people, choose $2$ of them, and choose $2$ from the $n-k$ left. That way we get the left sum.

The second way will be similar, look at the "leftest" $k$ people and choose $3$ of them, and then choose $1$ from the $n-k$ left. That gives the right side of the equation.

The only problem with this proof is that some of the options are counted twice and more, so it is not equal to ${n\choose 4.}$

Can someone help please? I would love to see both algebric and combinatorical proofs.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think you mean $$[x^n](1-x)^{-3}(1-x)^{-3}=[x^n](1-x)^{-4}(1-x)^{-2}.$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Pick **five** people from a row of $n+1$. The first sum counts
the possibilities based on the position of the middle person.
The second counts them based on the position of the fourth person.

Comment: I dont think I understand why. Can you explain a little bit deeper?

Comment: For the first sum, first take the person at position $k+1$. Then take $2$ of the $k$ people to their left and take $2$ of the $n-k$ people to their right. For the second sum, take $3$ of the people to their left and $1$ person to their right. This is similar to your initial approach, but now the person at position $k+1$ is also part of the selection (hence why we now pick $5$ people from $n+1$ total). This makes it so that selections that were originally counted multiple times, at different $k$, are now distinct from each other (as the person in position $k+1$ differs among those selections).